# Lie algebra with cyclic structure constants

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra (finite-dimensional, over a field) and a basis, denote the structure constants in the usual way: $[e_i,e_j]=\sum_kc_{ij}^ke_k$. We say that the structure constants are cyclic if $c_{ij}^k=c_{jk}^i$ for all $i,j,k$ (note that this depends on the choice of basis).

The Lie algebra being given, the existence of a basis with cyclic structure constant is a nontrivial condition as it can easily be checked not to exist in a non-abelian 2-dimensional Lie algebra.

> Which Lie algebras admit a basis with cyclic structure constants?

Comment: Why does $c^k_{ij} = c^i_{jk}$ define the semisimples? In $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, the bracket $\left[e,f\right]$ has a nonzero $h$-coordinate, but the bracket $\left[h,e\right]$ has no nonzero $f$-coordinate. Are you using a weirder basis?

Comment: Typo. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Endow your Lie algebra with the symmetric bilinear form making $\{e_i\}$ an orthornormal basis (the Gram matrix is the identity matrix). Since $c_{ij}^k=([e_i,e_j],e_k)$, what you call "cyclicity" is equivalent to the invariance of the form.

Comment: I rewrote the question hoping that it will it be reopened so that Victor's answer can be posted.

Comment: In (unnecessarily) fancy language, such a Lie algebra is an algebra over the *cyclic Lie operad*.

Comment: @Protsak: does it mean that every semi-simple Lie algebra over char zero field has cyclic structure constants? (Because the Killing form is symmetric and  non-degenerate)

Comment: I should add that the char zero field is algebraically closed

Comment: @YCor: Thank you, as a matter of fact, I was hoping the question could be reopened. Note that extra work is needed if the field is not algebraically closed or has char 2 (there exist even nondegenerate symmetric bilinear forms).

Comment: @Venky: Yes, with the additional assumptions you stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Endow your algebra with the symmetric bilinear form making $\{e_i\}$ an orthornormal basis (the Gram matrix is the identity matrix). Since $c_{ij}^k=([e_i,e_j],e_k)$, the cyclicity condition is equivalent to the invariance of the form:
$$
([e_i,e_j],e_k)=(e_i,[e_j,e_k]).
$$
Thus a finite-dimensional Lie algebra admits a basis with cyclic structure constants if and only if it admits an invariant symmetric bilinear form with Gram matrix the identity matrix. If the base field is algebraically closed not of characteristic 2, the latter condition simplifies to "admits a nondegenerate invariant symmetric bilinear form".

Comment: Also in the real case, this exists if and only if the Lie algebra is reductive compact. Interestingly, in the complex case, the class of such Lie algebras is much larger since they include non-reductive ones.

Comment: Yes, they are known as "quadratic Lie algebras".

Comment: They (Lie algebras endowed with an invariant symmetric bilinear form, or which admit at least such a form) have a multitude of names, which I tried to gather in Remark 2.5 in http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/Koszul.pdf.

Comment: Mind to give a small dimension example? (Non-semisimple, of course. Over the complex numbers is OK.)